# how to use interface in assemblyscript

Tags: typescript, webassembly, assemblyscript

I'm using [thegraph](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/assemblyscript-api/) which internally uses https://www.assemblyscript.org/

I'm trying to use interface, but it fails: `assert failed`.

```
export interface TransactionData {
  txHash: Bytes;
  timestamp: BigInt;
  logIndex: BigInt;
}
```

Doesn't assemblyscript support interfaces ? I also tried `export type` but get the `type expected` error.

Any idea ?

Comment: Are your types even valid ? BigInt is not a AssemblyScript type.